# PHP and SQL -- Select from database

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a problem with this code. It has syntax error and I don't know what is it.

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'id1381007_accounts';
$conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);

if (!$conn) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

$sql  = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=\"donat12@icloud.com\"';

echo $sql;
?>
```

Comment: execute your query by `mysqli_query($conn,$sql)` and change `'SELECT id FROM users WHERE email="donat12@icloud.com"'`

Comment: missing `}` just after `die()` statement

Comment: you don't need the backslashes in the sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issue with the code. First you forgot to close the if condition over here

> if (!$conn) {

And then you forgot to execute the sql query

the complete code would be like

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'id1381007_accounts';
$conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);

if (!$conn) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql  = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=\"donat12@icloud.com\"';
if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
   while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: And if I want to change the email address to a variable
For example (I know this code isn't good)
$email = donat12@icloud.com
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=$email';

Comment: Yes. you can just enclose it with single quotes like "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='".$emai.l"'" . Something like this. just check and try

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors

1. You are missing `}` closing bracket after `die`
2. Mysql query is wrong.

So the code should be

```
if (!$conn) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql  = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE email="donat12@icloud.com"';

echo $sql;
```